# Make Div Pairs Sit On Separate Lines Below Each Other

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to achieve something very simple but its just not working properly. 2 divs should sit next to each other (inline) but the next 2 divs should sit on the next line below (but also next to each other).

Please see my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9y6pt2yp/) for a simple example of the problem. You will see that the divs all sit next to each other (inline) on the same line. Maybe I need to explicitly define the `body` width or `.container` width? The problem is eventually these divs will slide

Do you know how I can make the 2 div pairs sit on below each other?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftDiv">
        <p>ITEM 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rightDiv">
        <p>BLURB: I SHOULD SIT RIGHT OF ITEM 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="leftDiv">
        <p>ITEM 2: I SHOULD SIT BELOW ITEM 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rightDiv">
        <p>BLURB: I SHOULD SIT RIGHT OF ITEM 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et do</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="leftDiv">
        <p>ITEM 3: I SHOULD SIT BELOW ITEM 2.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rightDiv">
        <p>BLURB: I SHOULD SIT RIGHT OF ITEM 3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
}

.leftDiv {
    width: 358px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
}

.rightDiv {
    width: 508px;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: [`clear:left;`](http://jsfiddle.net/9y6pt2yp/1/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't try to circumvent the rules by tagging words that aren't really code just so that you can post a JSFiddle link. It will get your questions downvoted and closed.

Comment: @TylerH Pardon you? By tagging words do you mean my the questions tags 'html' and 'css' which are completely relevant. Also I am well aware how to and when to post code in a question, adding a JS fiddle is a much neater and comprehend-able format for answerer's. If you wish to refute this then go an look at all the answers to HTML tagged questions and calculate the number of answers that post the solution as a JSFiddle link.

Comment: @Hoops No, I mean tagging the words `body` and `.container`; without tagging those words (Using the ` character around them), you would be disallowed from including a JSFiddle link in your post. This is because you need to share your code here, in case JSFiddle ever dies or is taken down for maintenance, etc.

Comment: @TylerH By your logic 75% of the answers to this question should be 'down voted and closed' and further, a similar majority of answers to questions tagged 'HTML', 'CSS' and 'Javascript' should also have the same result. See the error in your poorly thought out 'logic'? Are you seriously asserting that failing to add `<>` characters constitutes a user 'circumventing' the rules. Another case of moderators who are itching to use the tools/privileges they have been given rather than applying the tools/privileges when necessary and relevant

Comment: @Hoops I don't think you understand at all what I'm talking about. I'm not talking about the tags below your post, I'm talking about the words `body` and `.container` **in your post's body**. You added ` characters around them so that your post would contain "code" based on the site's built-in filter. In fact this is not actual code and is a circumvention, knowingly or not, of the JSfiddle link filter.

Comment: @TylerH I know from your previous comment you were referring to the 'body' and '.container' when you referred to tags. I had no idea this had an effect on SO's algorithms, I used code because body and .container are indeed HTML and CSS code. I also use it because it clearly communicates to the user that when I say body I mean the HTML code not the standard definition of body - notice how my use of 'body' in its standard form (in my last few sentences) can be confusing or ambiguous.

Comment: @TylerH Each aspect of my question from JSFiddle to formatting of HTML code as code were always for the purpose of comprehension and clarity to make it as easy as possible for someone to comprehend the problem (which if I just chuck a bunch of code in not many will take the time to parse it, understand what it does then make the effort to type a solution) and readability. Your assumption of circumvention is incorrect and you owe me an apology and need to re-assess your ability as a moderator and how effective you are as one.

Comment: @Hoops With your two most recent responses you've proven that you don't understand the situation, or you're intentionally trying to cover your tracks. At this site, you *are not allowed to post a JSFiddle link* unless you also include your code in the question. The system checks for this by seeing if you have any indented code or any code tagged with the ` character. You did not. Therefore, you circumvented the system. It's pretty cut and dry. Stop trying to act so offended because you did the wrong thing and didn't realize it and don't want to own up to it.

Comment: @TylerH Pardon you again! You cannot unwittingly circumvent and you owe me an apology for assuming and accusing myself of doing this. Why did you wait to communicate the rule that code must be present when you use a JSFiddle link until your 4th comment? Your first comment is not informing of this rule its an accusation that I circumvented some SO rule I am unaware of. You would do well as a moderator to use less wrong accusations and simply state a rule that has not been followed. If you believe that all let alone many are aware of this rule you are sorely mistaken

Comment: @Hoops I didn't wait, I said it in my **very first comment**; you just didn't understand me so I had to spend three more comments trying to get you to understand. You really need to re-examine your frame of reference here; you haven't accurately described anything that's been said so far. Instead of complaining to me about rules you don't know about or understand, you should just read them instead and stop trying to avoid the point, which is that *you* goofed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want http://jsfiddle.net/9y6pt2yp/5/

```
.leftDiv {
    clear: left;
}

.rightDiv {
    clear: right;
}
```

Comment: Nice simple cross-browser solution

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use `float: left;` then you'll have to understand that this takes the element out of the document flow - to make it part of the document flow, you'll have to use `overflow: hidden;` on it's parent element (or `height: 1%;` for older IE browsers).

That should fix the issue you are having. See my update to your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9y6pt2yp/7/

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can do:

Have a container div that spans 100% width of the page. Then within that you can place two div's each having `display:inline-block` and width around 50%. This itself should sufficiently serve you well.You don't need to add floats to achieve this as simple `display:inline-block` should suffice.

Here's how you need your HTML and CSS:

```css
.container {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    margin:20px auto;
}

.fLeft {
    display:inline-block;
    width:49.16%;
    background-color:Blue;
    margin:2px auto;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:White;
}

.fRight {
    color:White;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:green;
    display:inline-block;
    width:49.16%;
    
}
```

```html
<div clas="container">
    <div class="fLeft">ITEM 1</div>
    <div class="fRight">Right of ITEM 1</div>
</div>
<div clas="container">
    <div class="fLeft">ITEM 2</div>
    <div class="fRight">Right of ITEM 1</div>
</div>
<div clas="container">
    <div class="fLeft">ITEM 3</div>
    <div class="fRight">Right of ITEM 1</div>
</div>
<div clas="container">
    <div class="fLeft">ITEM 4</div>
    <div class="fRight">Right of ITEM 1</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
display: inline-block;
```

for .leftDiv & .rightDiv

Updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9y6pt2yp/4/